# Save image or animation in pyglet

Tags: python-2.7, save, gif, pyglet

I have an image saving issue. I need to take input of either a bmp, jpg, png, or gif and display it. The display part is fairly easy, the hard part is saving it. I want to take the user-supplied file and save it in a zipped directory that's going to be the save file for this project. I see that I can do pygletimage.save(filename) and get a png file. I'm fine with the format change for still images. The question is, how can I save a gif file easily in pyglet?

Comment: by gif, I'm specifically referring to the animated kind of gifs. Is there such a thing as pygletanimation.save(filename)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this function at every frame :

```
pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save(filename)
```

Here's the complete snippet. It saves whatever you display to numbered image files.

```
 #---EXPORT --------------------------------------------------------

    def save_a_frame(self):
            file_num=str(self.frame_number).zfill(5)
            file_t=str(self.chrono)
            filename="frame-"+file_num+'-@ '+file_t+'sec.png'
            pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save(filename)
            print 'image file writen : ',filename

    def export_loop(self,dt):
        constant_interval=1.0/PicPS
        if self.chrono<END_TIME:
            # update at a constant dt, regardless of real time
            # so that even if refresh is slow no frame should be missing
            # self.frame_draw(PicPS)
            self.update(constant_interval)
            self.frame_draw(dt)
            self.frame_number+=1
            self.save_a_frame()
        else:
            exit()
```

Comment: Would it save the entire gif as a single file? Or frame by frame?

Comment: So it's going to give me a series of .pngs. Which I'd then have to load as an animation the hard way, rather than saving the .gif. Is there a way I could just copy the file off immediately before displaying it? It's somewhat important to me that gifs be saved as gifs. jpgs, bmps, pngs, etc can all get simplified down into pngs, but I need gifs to stay as gifs.

Answer (score 0):

You can save each frame as a PNG via your `pygletimage.save()` method, then use the `imagemagick` command-line tool to combine those into a GIF like so:

```sh
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 frame_*.png animation.gif
```

See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/ for more information.